# How to store markers (with id) and populate map for each user using mongodb?

Tags: leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm a complete noob so bear with me please -

Currently users can add markers and my plan is to use the `ondraw` event to get the marker lat/lng and store that in mongodb, however i don't know how to get the individual markerID - `._leaflet_id` returns same id for every marker. 
But if i generate id for the marker using something like `Date.now()` how can i fetch that id from db if a user clicks on a marker? Each marker needs to be unique since each one will have a different redirect for `onclick()`.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please fix your formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue sometime back. What I did was create a table with [unique key id] and another column as markerJson,

```
var marker = new L.Marker([0, 0]);
// Get the GeoJSON object
var geojson = marker.toGeoJSON();
```

which has the following

```
{
    "type":"Feature",
    **"properties":{},**
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[0,0]
    }
}
```

Save the above json in markerjson Column created above.
You can see in the json above the properties feature   "properties":{}, does the logic
from db  fetch and append the [unique key id] to properties   "properties":{} e.g
 "properties":{unique-key_id:28}, now user can access the unique id from properties.

---

But in the case above  on creating an event, the create event has properties{} feature, just append _leaflet_id to properties with the generated Id with  Date.now().